# Proving a sequence has more then two subsequential limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Okay, so given $a_n$ with {$0,2$} $\subseteq P(a_n)$ and $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: |a_{n+1}-a_n|<1$ when $P(a_n)$ is the set of accumulation points.

I want to prove that the sequence has more then those two accumulation points mentioned above.

Inutitively it's pretty obvious I think. I have infinite members around $0$ and infinite members around $2$, so I think that there must be another accumulation point $1$ because of the given $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

The probelm is writing this formally, tried using the definition of accumulation point but got nowhere

thank you

Comment: What is $P(a_n)$? The set of all accumulation points?

Comment: As daw pointed out, you should write what $P(a_n)$ is, since it is not part of standard mathematical notation.

Comment: You're absolutely right, EDITED!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there are no accumulation points except for $0$ and $2$. Then in particular there are no accumulation points on $[1/3,5/3]$. Since the closed interval $[1/3,5/3]$ is compact, it follows that there are only finitely many points of the sequence $a_n$ in this interval (otherwise, there would be an accumulation point on this interval). Let $n=n_0$ be the largest $n$ for which $a_n\in[1/3,5/3]$. Then for $n>n_0$ either all $a_n<1/3$ or all $a_n>5/3$, because the sequence cannot jump over this interval. Hence either $0$ or $2$ is not an accumulation point of the sequence.

Exercise for the OP: show that the "additional" accumulation point is not necessarily $1$.

Comment: the question was edited

Comment: the answer was edited either.